# How to set numeric zip postal code lower limit in python?

Tags: python

My requirement is that an end user has to enter their zip/postal code (doesn't include alphanumeric ones). I have to set the upper limit and lower limit for the same, i.e. 00000 - 99999. This cannot be string. It has to be numeric. The issue, which all of you would have guessed, is 00000 will become 0. I know 00000 couldn't be a zip code (or maybe there are) but there are codes like 00020, 00578, etc.

```
LowerLimit = 00000
UpperLimit = 99999
```

Any suggestions as to how to go about?

Comment: `"0" * len(zipcode)` and `"9" * len(zipcode)`. You will have to use strings, because as you yourself noticed, `00020` will become `20` as an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading zeros are automatically terminated, so you can store the postal codes as strings since I don't think that you will ever need to add or subtract two postal codes?

```
p_code = str(20).zfill(5)
# this will generate a string -> 00020
```

and for comparison, you can convert them again to int() and check.